# Why an error occurs Status code was: -4 Termux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, termux

I installed ubuntu in termux and want to run a bot on selenium there
To do this, I installed Selenium via PIP and downloaded the official web driver from Githab and ran the initialization for the test but it gave me an error

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/root/firefox_driver/geckodriver')
```

Error

```
root@localhost:~# python3 test.py
test.py:5: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/root/firefox_driver/geckodriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/root/firefox_driver/geckodriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/firefox_driver/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

Comment: browser needs graphics environment `XWindows` to display window but as I know termux runs in text mode. And in text mode it may need to run in headless mode or it may need to use fake `XWindows` [Python: How to run Selenium on server without displaying window and GUI — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-scraping-how-to-run-selenium-on-server-without-displaying-window-and-GUI-gb.html)

Comment: @furas  No it seems that's not the case .... even when I use XFCE ubuntu  in Termux in which firefox and other windows perfectly start all the same I receive an error -4

Comment: so you can run firefox but you have problem with selenium? Maybe selenium uses wrong settings or wrong driver. There is module [Webdriver manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) which can automatically download driver and use correctl path. I see also that you have driver in folder `/root` and maybe it is wrong idea to use this folder - maybe it doesn't have access to files in this folder.